# Keras: model not learning when initializing weights

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

When setting initial model weights using Keras, the model does not update on subsequent training calls.

Example with MNIST data: (initial weights are random in example but will be passed in future iterations, therefore using a random kernel is not an option)

```
W1 = np.random.rand(784, n_nodes)
b1 = np.random.rand(n_nodes,)
W2 = np.random.rand(n_nodes, 10)
b2 = np.random.rand(10,)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(n_nodes, input_dim=784, activation='relu', weights=[W1,b1]))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', weights = [W2, b2]))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

for batch in batch_sets:
     model.train_on_batch(batch[0], batch[1])
```

I check the `b1` parameter through `get_weights()` in each iteration and can see that no update is being made from the original, random `b1`.

I have also tried using `set_weights` as well as a custom kernel (and bias) initializer and am experiencing the same issue. The same issue of no updates is also occurring when the kernel initializer is set to ones or zeros, but the behavior is as expected (aka updating appropriately) when a random kernel initializer is used.

Is there an alternative way to set initial weights that allows them to be updated on subsequent model training calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `weights=` parameter is replacing what usually gets put in the `.weights` property of the `Layer`, which are TensorFlow variables. Replacing variables with numpy arrays means they get embedded as constants in the TensorFlow graph instead, which means the optimizer ignores them (they're constants!).

Instead, you can pass the numpy arrays as initializers for the kernel and bias: `Dense(kernel_initializer=w1, bias_initializer=b1, ...`